# MDF connection string property is not working in the code

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I view my MDF file properties in C# I can see property named `Connection String` and its value is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\itay\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chat\Chat\App_Data\ChatDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

When I'm trying to use this code in my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\itay\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Chat\\Chat\\App_Data\\ChatDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Value", con);

SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
con.Close();
```

When I try to use it - it throws:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

I tried a few more connection strings formats that I've found in SO but with no success.

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: Where do the exception occur? What is the message?

Comment: Remove the extra backslash after `ChatDB.mdf` in your coded connection string. Filenames don't have a trailing backslash. (Voting to close this question as being caused by a typo. You really should learn to carefully proofread your code.)

Comment: I suspect you aren't escaping the `\v11.0` and it's interpreting `\v` as a vertical tab.

Comment: Also FYI [Bad habits : Using AttachDBFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename)

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character has a special meaning in C#. It introduces an escape sequence. To use that connection string directly in C# as a literal string you need to prefix it with the verbatim character `@` and remove all the doubling of the `\` backslash introduced in your literal string.
Notice that you could use also a single quote around the path of the database file removing another point of confusion

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\itay\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chat\Chat\App_Data\ChatDB.mdf';Integrated Security=True");
```

If you prefer to use the actual format then you need to also double the backslash between `Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;`

[An interesting reading about C# strings, escape sequences and verbatim literals](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Comment: Not sure why this is not selected as the answer

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string you also need to escape `\v` with `\\v`, because it represents vertical tab - see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).